# Error trying to scaffold Controller in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, api, entity-framework-core

I have created a new ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project and I'm using an existing MYSQL database.
I managed to scaffold models and context from the database without problems.

But when i try to scaffold controller, either when using the Add -> Controller -> API -> API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework (in solution explorer) or using dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator controller command in Package Manager Console i get the following error:
[image]
[image]

I have googled around for solutions but can't seem to find any.

I'm new to C#/Visual Studio/.NET/EntityFramework (I'm used to using node.js) so any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before with a lower version of EF Core caused by some kind of cs syntax , helping me install the package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` . Мaybe your problem is the same and I hope this helps you.

Comment: I get this error: 

Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common. Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.1.0 directly to project api-test to resolve this issue. 
 api-test -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.1.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.1.0) 
 api-test -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.2 -> Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared 6.0.2 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features 4.0.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.0.0).